# Using SQL query to find the ID of the question with the longest text

Tags: sql, postgresql

I typed the following SQL code in [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) using PostgreSQL v14 as the database engine to create the QUESTION relation.

```
CREATE TABLE QUESTION 
(
    ID TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    SurveyScreenID TEXT,
    QuestionNumber INT,
    QuestionText TEXT
);

INSERT INTO QUESTION (ID, SurveyScreenID, QuestionNumber, QuestionText) VALUES
('dvif_s1_q1','dvif_s1',1,'How many vegetables did you eat today?'),
('dvif_s1_q2','dvif_s1',2,'What was the tastiest?'),
('dvif_s1_q3','dvif_s1',3,'What was the least tasty?'),
('dfif_s1_q1','dfif_s1',1,'How much fruit did you eat today?'),
('dfif_s1_q2','dfif_s1',2,'What was the tastiest?'),
('dfif_s1_q3','dfif_s1',3,'What was the least tasty?'),
('dfif_s2_q1','dfif_s2',1,'How many pieces were underripe?'),
('dfif_s2_q2','dfif_s2',2,'How many pieces were rotten?'),
('dfif_s3_q1','dfif_s3',1,'Would you recommend eating fruit to a friend?'),
('dfif_s3_q2','dfif_s3',2,'Why or why not?'),
('dnif_s1_q1','dnif_s1',1,'How many nuts did you eat today?'),
('dnif_s1_q2','dnif_s1',2,'What was the tastiest?'),
('dnif_s1_q3','dnif_s1',3,'What was the most disgusting?'),
('dnif_s3_q1','dnif_s3',1,'Would you recommend eating nuts to a friend?'),
('dnif_s3_q2','dnif_s3',2,'If yes, why, and if no, why not?');
```

I wrote the following SQL query to find the ID of the question with the longest text:

```
SELECT ID
FROM QUESTION
WHERE length(QuestionText) = MAX(length(QuestionText));
```

However, the program returned a query error saying

> Query error: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is easily explained: In the `WHERE` clause we look at single rows, so you can use `length(QuestionText)` because this is the row's text length, but you cannot use `MAX(length(QuestionText))`, because your row has no information about the maximum text length in the table.

You need another query, a subquery, to find the maximum length in your query. The answers of Deepstop and sankar show you how.

There is a simpler way, though. You want the top ID(s) according to their text length. So, order by text length and pick the top rows with `FETCH FIRST ROW`. Use the `WITH TIES` clause, because there can be more than one ID with the maximum text length.

```
select id
from question
order by length(questiontext) desc
fetch first row with ties;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put a subquery in a WHERE clause, so try this.

```
SELECT ID, questiontext
    FROM question
    WHERE length(questiontext) =
        (SELECT max(length(questiontext)) FROM question)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on length, allowing efficient searches: and use subquery on max length.

```
CREATE INDEX que_length_qt_idx ON question (length(questiontext));

SELECT ID
FROM QUESTION
WHERE length(QuestionText) = (SELECT MAX(length(QuestionText)) FROM QUESTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid subquery poor performance, you can make a JOIN with max length question text with an inline table:

```
select Q.ID 
from QUESTION Q join 
(
  select MAX (LENGTH (QuestionText)) MX_LEN_Q 
  from QUESTION
) T_MAX 
on LENGTH (Q.QuestionText) = T_MAX.MX_LEN_Q;
```

Comment: What gives you the idea that subqueries have a poor performance? This is plain wrong.

Comment: In the Jet database engine (used by MS-Access), this would make a huge difference, but not in PostgreSQL.